# Breaking If statements.. Clicking a button once

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, libgdx, break

I am trying to make a keyboard and everything works fine. I just want to break the if statement after each click to stop repetitiveness of the char. I don't want to use a Boolean because user can enter same character more than once. This is the image listener

```
 a = new Image(new Texture("Sprites/Keyboard/a.png"));
    a.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

            apressed = true;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

            apressed= false;

        }

    });
```

And this is what i have in my update inside the activity or state.

```
 @Override
 public void handleInput() {

   if (keyboard.apressed) {

            builder.append('A');
            currentWord = builder.toString();
            //break; here doesn't work. says its outside the loop.

        }
 }
```

So in theory this is what i want but can't use because im guessing its to much work for every char?

```
 @Override
 public void handleInput() {

 if (keyboard.apressed) {

            builder.append('A');
            currentWord = builder.toString();
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(400);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error");
            }
        }
```

any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. I think you should clarify a little

Comment: your are referring to a "loop", but I don't see any loop in your code...  every trigger to the InputListener is a single execution, not a loop.. your question is not very clear..

Comment: look at the last example and you will understand what i want to do. If you click a button it will register more than one click . I want the button to add one char with every tap or touch down followed by touch up.

Comment: Can you show where are you using the if block?

Comment: I believe you should use the event keyTyped instead of keyPressed

Comment: inside the update method.. also i am not using keypressed that is just a boolean. It is a virtual keyboard

Comment: there are a multitude of ways to get what you want. But the way you are implementing things seems to use an immense amount of code which you don't need if you abstract things.

I would start by creating a "KeyboardButton" class which extends the image button, holds a character and has a callback to add a character to the currently focussed field.

Never ever ever use a sleep on the render thread, unless you actually want the users device to freeze.

Comment: yeah i had a feeling that i was doing something wrong with the sleep. I know the code is not perfect it is bits and pieces put together to get what i want. : )

Comment: does using sleep in the update method also causes freezing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own keyboard as well using LibGDX TextButtons. Since you are using images and not text, you could use the ImageButton instead. I then used the ChangeListener with the changed() method because it only triggers after pressing and releasing the button, which avoids repetitive characters while the button is being pressed.

```
keyButton.addCaptureListener(new ChangeListener() {
@Override
    public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor){
        // key logic here
```